Is there a software for several Ubuntu computers where I can log the CPU, Memory and GPU usage over time?
I am looking for an open-source and simple solution. It also can be a script. I want to get an overview over the team, if I need to upgrade hardware.
Honestly, I tried to google, but I haven't found something useful. If I can get some useful keywords to search, I would be happy.
I would also be happy for a script (code), which connects to each computer and logs it every 2 hours.

Crossposting is not tolerated. Check sar, it can "monitor" CPU, memory, I/O

sar actually looks interesting.   But why "monitor". You mean just save output into text file?

Monitoring is common word for collecting performance information :) And yes, sar store this info in files from where you can run reports with desired frequency.

What about Logstash, part of the Elasticsearch project?

Logstash is an open source data collection engine with real-time pipelining capabilities. Logstash can dynamically unify data from disparate sources and normalize the data into destinations of your choice. Cleanse and democratize all your data for diverse advanced downstream analytics and visualization use cases.

You could collect GPU metrics with an extra script, e.g. calling nvidia-smi periodically, and then process output of that script with Logstash.

Pay attention to Zabbix and Nagios.
Both solutions are deployed on the server and collect the necessary data from the hosts.

Nagios is an open source program designed to monitor computer systems
and networks: monitoring, controlling the state of computing nodes and
services, notifying the administrator if any of the services stop
working.


Zabbix is ​​a free system for monitoring the status of various
computer network services, servers and network equipment, written by
Alexey Vladyshev. MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite or Oracle Database are
used to store data, the web interface is written in PHP. Supports
several types of monitoring:

Simple checks - can check the availability and response of standard services, such as SMTP or HTTP, without installing any software on the
monitored host.
Zabbix agent - can be installed on UNIX-like or Windows hosts to obtain data on processor load, network usage, disk space, etc.
External check - execution of external programs, monitoring via SNMP is also supported.



Thanks. but I don't want that a third party collects my data.

@j35t3r What I meant was that you can install any of these products on your own equipment, and the data will be stored on your own.

Oh. Sorry. then i have misunderstood something.
